# Push result of HttpClient to BehaviorSubject and observe changes in the UI

Tags: angular

I have a small service that does a `POST` request to the backend. The result of that `POST` should be pushed onto a `BehaviorSubject` which is consumed throughout the Angular application.

At the moment in the UI (template), I can see a new record being added, so I know the `BehaviorSubject` has triggered correctly, but the object that gets pushed looks to be empty.

How I'm pushing the `POST` result

```js
private history$: BehaviorSubject<Job[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Job[]>([]);


private startJob(type: string) {
    return this.httpClient.post<Job>(`${this.endpoint}?type=${type}`, null).subscribe((result: Job) => {
        this.history$.next([...this.history$.value, result]);
    });
}
```

Listening to that in a component with

```js
history$: Observable<Job[]> = new Observable<Job[]>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.history$ = this.jobService.findAll();
}
```

Rendering it in the template

```html
<div class="section" *ngIf="jobs$ | async as jobs; else noJobs">
    [...]
    <tr *ngFor="let job of jobs">
        <td>{{ job.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ job.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ job.data }}</td>
        <td>{{ job.startTime | amCalendar }}</td>
        <td>{{ job.endTime | amCalendar }}</td>
    </tr>
    [...]
</div>
```

So, nothing fancy here. However I'm seeing the new row being added, but it has no values.

Logging the result from the `POST` it all has data as it should, I'm sure I've done it just like this many times in the past so a little unsure where I've gone wrong here.

Comment: "_but the object that gets pushed looks to be empty_" - where are you checking this object - in the service, in a component, or in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure from your example, but at a guess it's because your using a BehaviorSubject :

```
private history$: BehaviorSubject<Job[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Job[]>([]);
```

A BehaviorSubject should be used when you replayability, but you *also* want there to be a default value. So when you say :

> The object that gets pushed looks to be empty

That would be correct because when you initialize a BehaviorSubject, you have to give it a default value and in your case, you've given it the default value of [].

If you change your code to instead use a ReplaySubject like so :

```
private history$: ReplaySubject<Job[]> = new ReplaySubject<Job[]>(1);
```

You should have a better time.

For more info on Subject vs ReplaySubject vs BehaviorSubject, see here : https://tutorialsforangular.com/2020/12/12/subject-vs-replaysubject-vs-behaviorsubject/